# How can I improve my milky way photographs?

Tags: astrophotography, long-exposure, milky-way

I am new to the astrophotography world. My camera is a Canon SL2 and I use a Tokina 11-16mm trying to shoot the milky way at 14mm I noticed that my milky way shots do not look remotely close to some of the pictures I have seen from other photographers. While the milky way is visible it seems to be distorted in a way that does not look as bold as some of the pictures I have seen. I do shoot in RAW and my settings are 30"|F2.8|ISO 800. Is there a way to fix this issue in post-processing or in my settings? Or is the fact my camera is ASPC has something to do with the way the milky way is showing up?

[image]

Comment: Related questions: [How do I capture the milky way?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/37261), [How to have colors in Milky-way?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/43028)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have colors in Milky-way?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43028/how-to-have-colors-in-milky-way)

Answer (score 6):

Your biggest challenge seems to be finding a place where the sky is dark enough. [Light pollution](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/106684/15871) is washing out the finer details of the night sky.

Beyond that, your lens seems to be poorly focused on the stars and is also exhibiting a considerable amount of chromatic aberration.

Answer (score 3):

Those pictures you’re trying to reproduce are using mounts to cancel earth rotation, stacking of multiple images and **heavy** postprocessing. A tutorial workflow can be seen here: https://pixinsight.com/forum.old/index.php?topic=5516.0 Note that PixInsight is one of the few (commercial) software packages for postprocessing astro images, but similar postprocessing can be done with other software, too.

First ISO800 seems rather low, make sure the histogram is at least in the middle. Beware of burnt out (overflowing) stars, though.

Then you‘ve certainly captured RAWs, haven‘t you? If not, do so.

Then don‘t be shy with the knobs in Lightroom or what you‘re using. Astrophotography is at the extremes of what‘s possible and also needs extreme settings in processing.

Then the natural next step is stacking:
Take multiple exposures and stacking them, e.g. in [DeepSkyStacker](http://deepskystacker.free.fr/english/index.html) or [SiriL](https://siril.org/).

One further step then will be using a mount, that cancel‘s earth‘s rotation. For Milkyway have a look at LX2/LX3, Vixen Polarie, SkyTracker Pro or StarAdventurer mounts. If you’re on a budget, build a [Barndoor tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barn_door_tracker) yourself.